# Bash: iterate with variable on the lines of `ls -1` output

Tags: shell-script, ls

In a simple cycle like the following

```
for f in $(ls -1) ;
        do
        something
done
```

I would like to store each *line* of the output of `ls -1` in the variable `f`.

Is there a way to do this without setting `IFS=$'\n'`?

Comment: Don't parse `ls`!

Comment: Within the loop, you _can_ access each line of output using the variable `f`.

Comment: Moreover, there are far too many questions that iterate over the results of `find`, even `ls`.  Seems that you want to store the result into an array, though.

Comment: @devnull I don't actually need an array, but sometimes there are filenames with spaces: they are considered like different files, so I need to iterate over the lines. What do you mean with "don't parse `ls`"?

Comment: You could use `find` instead.  Search for `find`, `-print0`.

Comment: He means [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) precisely because that causes the type of problem you are facing.

Comment: `ls -q` should help.

Comment: Also don't use filenames with spaces :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As we said in the comments, [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) it is prone to errors and completely unnecessary anyway. All you need is

```
for f in *;
do
        something
done
```

That will iterate through the files and directories<sup>1</sup> in your current directory and save each of them (spaces and all) as `$f`. For example:

```
$ ls -A1
file1
file 2
$ for f in *; do echo "File is '$f'"; done
File is 'file1'
File is 'file 2'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In bash, this will ignore files/directory names starting with `.` (hidden files) unless you have set `dotglob` with `shopt -s dotglob`.

Comment: You can do `ls -q` - but I like your shell glob better. Personally I prefer `( set -- * )` because then I get them all at the same time addressable as `$1 $2 $3...` or in the shell `$@` array. The end result is the same though - because I'll inevitably use a `while` or `until` loop anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv `-q` does not help at all, it just replaces control characters with `?` so yes, a `\n` will be shown as `?` but that will just break the script (since you can't actually use the file since its name does not contain a literal `?`) and in any case, the `-q` will still fail on file names with spaces.

Comment: Well, if you've got that much you can get the file name by simply expanding the variable. And it doesn't fail if `$IFS` is handled correctly. That's why they use `?` - its a shell glob for any character. In any case, this will portably handle setting all positionals to .dot or not files: `for glob in ".[!.]*" "[!.]*" ; do set -- $glob "$@" &&  [ -e "./$1" ] || shift ; done  `

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop instead:

```
$ touch "one file"
$ touch "second  file   edsfs"
$ ls
one file  second  file   edsfs
$ ls -1
one file
second  file   edsfs
$ for f in $(ls -1); do echo "\"$f\""; done
"one"
"file"
"second"
"file"
"edsfs"
$ while read f; do echo "\"$f\""; done < <(ls -1)
"one file"
"second  file   edsfs"
```

Comment: Yes, the while loop helps deal with spaces. It does not, however, help deal with filenames with newlines or, backslashes. Really, just don't parse `ls`. Ever.